# how to not add extra list bracket for a dictionary key where values are already in list

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am doing one operation on dictionary, where i want to add or append all values with same keys together, my values are list of dictionary.

```
{'test': [{'Workvalue': [{'for': 'red', 'pro': 'valpr'}, {'for': 'valtest2', 'pro': 'valpr2'}, {'for': 'testing purpose', 'pro': 'testing urpos'}]}, {'WorkLimit': [{'for': 'FLR1', 'pro': 'PLR1'}, {'for': 'FLR2', 'pro': 'PLR2'}]}, {'WorkLimit': [{'for': 'FLR3'}, {'for': 'DAV', 'pro': 'DDAA'}]}]}
```

I want following output:

```
{'test': [{'Workvalue': [{'for': 'valtest', 'pro': 'valpr'}, {'for': 'valtest2', 'pro': 'valpr2'}, {'for': 'testing purpose', 'pro': 'testing urpos'}], 'WorkLimit': [{'for': 'FLR1', 'pro': 'PLR1'}, {'for': 'FLR2', 'pro': 'PLR2'}], [{'for': 'FLR3'}, {'for': 'DAV', 'pro': 'DDAA'}]]}}
```

I am getting this result with my code:

```
{'test': [{'Workvalue': [[{'for': 'valtest', 'pro': 'valpr'}, {'for': 'valtest2', 'pro': 'valpr2'}, {'for': 'testing purpose', 'pro': 'testing urpos'}]], 'WorkLimit': [[{'for': 'FLR1', 'pro': 'PLR1'}, {'for': 'FLR2', 'pro': 'PLR2'}], [{'for': 'FLR3'}, {'for': 'DAV', 'pro': 'DDAA'}]]}]}
```

I am getting extra list bracket , but i dont want that.

code i am using trying:

```
value = {
        k: [d.get(k) for d in data['test'] if d.get(k) is not None]
        for k in set().union(*data['test])
        }
```

Comment: 1) This isn't your code (you have typos that prevent it from being even syntactically valid). 2) The extra list brackets are due to your inner listcomp; you can always [flatten them away](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/364696) once you've combined the stuff you care about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `d.get(k)` returns an array. However, you can simply use its elements instead of the whole array:

```
value = {
        k: [element for d in data['test'] if d.get(k) is not None for element in d.get(k)]
        for k in set().union(*data['test'])
        }
```

Output:

```
{'WorkLimit': [{'for': 'FLR1', 'pro': 'PLR1'}, {'for': 'FLR2', 'pro': 'PLR2'}, {'for': 'FLR3'}, {'for': 'DAV', 'pro': 'DDAA'}], 'Workvalue': [{'for': 'red', 'pro': 'valpr'}, {'for': 'valtest2', 'pro': 'valpr2'}, {'for': 'testing purpose', 'pro': 'testing urpos'}]}
```